# Rerun cyclic job once on failure/delayed file to file watcher in Autosys

Tags: autosys

We have one job which runs twice in a day at 09:00AM and at 09:00PM (Cyclic job).

Now condition is, if job get fail at 09:00AM then it should rerun once after failure/any other delay in receiving files to file watcher job, but it also trigger again at 09:00PM.

So any idea's on how to configure this?

Thanks in advance....!!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have the file watcher job configured with 12 hours interval, attribute term_run_time.

A file watcher fails only when the file is not received in the specified interval if there are no issues with the script and ; continues to run if the file is not received if the interval is not up.

So, if the delay is within the term_run_time interval you should not worry about the restarting the job as the job would wait for the 12 hours.

Again, the failure should be handled in appropriate way.

For failure, if it all you really want to have the job re-run you can set the starting job dependency as FA(Same_job_name).

However, IMHO you should not have such a design. The better way is to choose the term_run_time appropriately to handle the file arrival behavior wrt time.

Answer (score 0):

Better option would be attribute n_retrys: , here you can specify the number of time the job should rerun after fail. This attribute will rerun the job, if it fails.